# How to show event Timer in mvc using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing Appointment schedule Application ,i need timer for each appointment event using full calendar.
I want to show event timer so that i can enable/disable Call button as per timer.

Plz help?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any luck so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

**Set current Date**

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo =   TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Timezonename");

 var d = new Date('@DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimeZoneTime(timeZoneInfo)');
```

**Calculate Remaining time**

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(d);
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    var timeinterval;
```

**Initilize Clock**

```
var timeinterval;
    function initializeClock(endtime){
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            if(t.total<0)
            {
                t.seconds =((-1)*parseInt(t.seconds))-1;
                t.minutes = ((-1)*parseInt(t.minutes))-1;
                t.hours = ((-1)*parseInt(t.hours))-1;
                t.days =  ((-1)*parseInt(t.days))-1;
            }

            t.days= t.days<=9?'0'+t.days:t.days
            t.hours= t.hours<=9?'0'+t.hours:t.hours
            t.minutes= t.minutes<=9?'0'+t.minutes:t.minutes
            t.seconds= t.seconds<=9?'0'+t.seconds:t.seconds


            var text=(t.days>0)?t.days  + ' d ':'';

            if(t.total<=0){

                    text='Started '
                    text+=(t.days>0)?t.days  + ' d ':'';
                    text+=(t.hours>0) || (t.days>0)?t.hours  + ' h ':'';
                    text+=(t.minutes>0) || (t.hours>0)?t.minutes  + ' m ':'';
                    text+=(t.seconds>0) || (t.minutes>0)?t.seconds  + ' s ago ':'';

            }
            else{

                text+=(t.hours>0) || (t.days>0)?t.hours  + ' h ':'';
                text+=(t.minutes>0) || (t.hours>0)?t.minutes  + ' m ':'';
                text+=(t.seconds>0) || (t.minutes>0)?t.seconds  + ' s left ':'';
            }
            clock.text(text);
        },1000);
    }
```